# how to define dimens for multiResolution in android studio

Tags: android, resources, dimension

I use Android Studio version 1.2.2

i want to build App in MultiResolution
So i used dimens.xml for some resolutions, but it not works well and always show **mdpi** resources

[image: dimens.xml]

In AndroidManifest.xml i put :

```
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true"/>
```

there is dimens.xml for **Four Resolutions**, Tested on Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1" (Density 4), But not works well
So whats wrong on this project ?

Solved, dimens.xml should set to whole resolutions as

[image: dimens.xml]

Density programmatically shows 4, but in xml should set values for sw720dp.

Comment: how do you know it's not working?

Comment: What is not working, and in what way ? Post your dimens.xml files.

Comment: it always return dimens.xml(mdpi) resources. textsize is always mdpi for whole densities

Comment: @sadeghsaati sadegh dada, feghat maghadire mdpi ro dar dimens.xml bar migardune, baraye tablet o ... ham hamine !!!

Comment: screen density is independent from screen size ,the tablet screen resolutions might be mdpi too

Comment: @sadeghsaati checked programmatically, Density 4, Galaxy tab 2 10.1" is not mdpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But for that you should add

```
<supports-screens 
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"
  android:resizeable="true"/>
```

in your `manifest.xml`

Check this article [multiple-screen-support-in-android-using-android-studio](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/multiple-screen-support-in-android-using-android-studio/)

Comment: Problem was : programmatically density shows 4, but on xml it is sw720dp